# How to read a value from a xml column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

Given:

```
mySql table with a column containing xml
```

Find:

```
sql query extracting a value
```

preferred Usage:

```
select ExtractValue(xmlColumn, 'xPath/to/value') from table;
```

Knowledge:

here first a xml element has to be set

```
set @xml
select ExtractValue(@xml, 'xPath/to/value);
```

how to set my xml column as @xml in one query ?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that it works as I intuitivly wrote in the question

```
select ExtractValue(myColumn, 'myPath/to/value') from table;
```

does the job